# What is the error "cannot match against a tuple struct which contains private fields"?

Tags: rust

What is the error "cannot match against a tuple struct which contains private fields"?
I'm getting an error like this for web::Path(id). How can I resolve it?

```rust
use actix_web::{get, post, web, HttpResponse,Responder};
use crate::model::todo::*;
#[get("/todos/{id}")]
async fn get_todo(web::Path(id): web::Path<u32>) -> impl Responder {
    println!("get_todo");
    let id_option: Option<u32> = Some(id);
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(Todo {
        id: id_option,
        content: String::from("やること"),
        completed: false,
    })
}

#[post("/todos")]
async fn post_todo(todo: web::Json<Todo>) -> impl Responder {
    println!("post_todo");
    println!("{:?}", todo);
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("ok")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The field of the struct [`actix_web::web::Path`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Path.html) is private so you cannot pattern match on it to extract the inner value; you need to call [`.into_inner()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Path.html#method.into_inner). This should work:

```rust
#[get("/todos/{id}")]
async fn get_todo(id: web::Path<u32>) -> impl Responder {
    println!("get_todo");
    let id_option: Option<u32> = Some(id.into_inner());
    ...
}
```